# Numbers not matching

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, matching

I'm new to excel vba and have just written some code to track if a game participant has paid their debt or not.

I'll simplify the code here

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).Value Then
   'Do something
Else 'Do something else
End If
```

The value in `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value` is 1
And the value in `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).Value` is also 1, but excel is saying they are not matching

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: They aren't both exactly 1 then. Maybe you need to `WorksheetFunction.Round` them.

Comment: Another possibility is that one of them is the number 1, and the other is a string that looks like the number 1.

Comment: Thanks guys, I converted them both to integer's and it worked. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1

```
Sub New()    
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).Value Then
               Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1,1).Value="Paid"
            Else 
            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1,1).Value="Not Paid"
            End If
        end sub
```

**2**

```
 Sub New()  
dim str as string
dim i,a as integer
  i=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
a=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1).Value
    If i =a  Then
           Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1,1).Value="Paid"
        Else 
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1,1).Value="Not Paid"
        End If
    end sub
```